# Dialogflow: How to change default phrase in Agent Webpage -console

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es

At the bottom of the web demo console is says:
Ask something...

Is it possible to change this into a different language ?
I am making a chatbot in Norwegian language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you are creating your agent just select Norwegian as the only language. You'll probably have to change your device language as well.

Update: Actually I managed to change my device language and browser language to Norwegian and it still showed the prompt in English.

One definite work around is to use your own web client and the detect intent API.